# Abstract Algebra: Finding if the inverse element exists in $\Bbb C^*$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm having trouble with the second to last part (part 4) of this abstract algebra question. So below, I will write out the problem, then my answers for the other parts. Please let me know if I did any other part wrong!

### Problem

Define $\odot$ on $\Bbb C^*$ according to:
$$(a + bi) \odot (c + di) = ac + bdi$$

1. Is $\odot$ well-defined? In other words, is $\Bbb C^*$ closed under $\odot$?
2. Is $\odot$ associative? If you think it is, prove it. If you do not think so, explain, or provide a
   counterexample.
3. Find, if possible, an element $e$ such that $e\odot z = z$ for any $z \in \Bbb C^*$. Or, explain why such
   an element does not exist.
4. Based on the identity element you found in (3), find the inverse of a typical element $z$ in $\Bbb C^*$, or explain why it may not exist.
5. Is $\langle\Bbb C^*, \odot\rangle$ a group? Explain.

### My Answers

1. No. This is because our result can be zero, consider the case $$(a) \odot (i) = a*0 + 0*i = 0$$
   Since zero is not in $\Bbb C^*$, we know $\odot$ is not closed.
2. Yes. We want to show (AB)C = A(BC). That is,
   $$[(a + bi) \odot (c + di)] \odot (e + fi)= (a + bi) \odot [(c + di) \odot (e + fi)]$$
   $$(ac + bdi) \odot (e + fi)= (a + bi) \odot (ce + dfi)$$
   $$(ace + bdfi) = (ace + bdfi)$$
3. By inspection, we can see that $e = 1 + i$. We can test to make sure. Let $z = a + bi$.
   $$e \odot z = (1 + i) \odot (a + bi) = (a + bi) = z$$

### Where I'm Stuck

Here, I can't quite figure out 4. I think it has something to do with the inverse element not always existing, because it can be zero somehow? And the answer to 5 depends on the answer to 4!

Comment: What's $\mathbb C^\ast$? The group of units? Because then consider $1\odot i=0$ for the first question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure $\Bbb C^*$ is the set of all non-zero complex numbers. But I do see your point.

Comment: Then the above comment implies that the operation is not well defined. You say that $ac$ and $bd$ are not zero, that's wrong.

Comment: Yes, I see that now, I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: And for question 4, take any $a+bi\in\mathbb c^\ast$. What is its inverse, that is, which $c+di$ fulfills $(a+bi)\odot(c+di)=1+i$?

Comment: For specific counter example, does there exist $(a + bi)$ such that $(a + bi) \odot (1 +[i\times 0]) = (1 + i)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inverse element **would** be $$(a+ib)^{-1}=\dfrac{1}{a}+i\dfrac{1}{b}.$$ The problem is that the condition $a+ib \in \mathbb{C}^*$ means that $a$ and $b$ cannot be simultaneously equal to $0$. But if $a=0$ or $b=0$, then $a+ib$ does not have an inverse element.